# How to mock an input with MatSidenav type, in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine

It is possible to mock the MatSidenav?

I want to unit test a component which has as input a MatSidenav from the parent component.

So far I get this errors in karma window:

Error #1:

> ChildComponent > should create
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'runOutsideAngular' of null

Error #2:

> ChildComponent > on sidenav change should work
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'runOutsideAngular' of null

I understand the error are because I mock the super class with null parameters, can someone show me a better solution on this?

My code looks like this.

### parent-component.html

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>

  <mat-sidenav #filtersSidenav mode="side" opened="true" position="end"></mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <app-child-component [sidenav]="filtersSidenav"></app-child-component >
  </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

### app-child-component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  templateUrl: './app-child-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-child-component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() sidenav: MatSidenav;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.sidenav) {
      this.sidenav.openedChange.subscribe( res => {
        console.log('works');
      });
    }
  }

}
```

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';

// Modules
import { MaterialModule } from '@app-global-modules/material.module.ts';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

// Components
import { ChildComponent } from './child-component.component';

// Other
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


class SidenavMock extends MatSidenav {

  openedChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>(true);

  constructor() {
    super(null, null, null, null, null, null);
  }

}


describe('ChildComponent', () => {

  let component: ChildComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChildComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        ChildComponent,
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));


  beforeEach(async() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChildComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;


    component.sidenav = new SidenavMock(); // <== I mock

    component.ngOnInit();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });


  fit('on sidenav change should work', () => {
    const consoleLogSpy = spyOn(console, 'log').and.callThrough();
    component.sidenav.toggle();

    expect(consoleLogSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('works');
  });


});
```

Comment: Would the shallow testing approach be sufficient for you? With that you would use the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, and wouldn‘t import the MaterialModule but rather only declare the necessary material directives as a stub. Have a look here, that‘s a test setup for a component with a different material component: https://stackblitz.com/edit/directive-testing-17bcms

Comment: @George C. have you found a fix for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can u try:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'testing-component',
    template: `
        <mat-sidenav-container>

        <mat-sidenav #filtersSidenav mode="side" opened="true" position="end"></mat-sidenav>

        <mat-sidenav-content>
            <app-child-component [sidenav]="filtersSidenav"></app-child-component >
        </mat-sidenav-content>

        </mat-sidenav-container>
    `
})
class TestBedComponent {
    @ViewChild(ChildComponent) public componentUnderTest: ChildComponent ;    
    constructor() {}
}
```

In spec file:

```
// Components
import { ChildComponent } from './child-component.component';
// Other
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


describe('ChildComponent', () => {

  let component: TestBedComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestBedComponent>;
  let childComponent: ChildComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        ChildComponent,TestBedComponent
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));


  beforeEach(async() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestBedComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    childComponent = component.componentUnderTest;
  });


  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(childComponent).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This way of testing often preferred when there is some tightly coupled data which the child component requires (as I can see in your case).

You can keep on testing `childComponent` in the similar fashion as you do when you  `component` in a spec file.

Comment: Hi @Shashank Vivek, thanks for your answer, I have read it, but I think you forget the mock part, I am trying to trigger the sidenav subscription,

```
this.sidenav.openedChange.subscribe( res => {
        console.log('works');
      });
```
since I cant find a way to create or mock the sidenav

Comment: @GeorgeC. Did u try calling `childComponent.sidenav.toggle()` ?? In my case, you are getting the actual `MatSidenav ` so U shouldn;'t worry about Mocking it. PLease check and confirm. If there is any error, please share that as well

Comment: Hi, sry for the late response, I try your code but I get this error ```
Property 'componentUnderTest' does not exist on type 'childComponent'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: @GeorgeC. Can u provide error screen shot and your respective code screenshot. Because, as per your error : `componentUnderTest` is expected from `childComponent` which is definitely a correct error. I have created `componentUnderTest` under `TestBedComponent ` for testing purpose.

Comment: Nope your example does not work. I am trying to  create a stackbliz  example now, so you understand better.

Comment: @GeorgeC. Sure, please `@` me after adding the link